# Автоматическая подстановка тире

Tags: java, android-edittext

**Цель**: писал поле для ввода номера снилс, и делал, чтобы он сам ставил тире через каждые три символа.

**Проблема**: не смог найти нужную информацию.

**Как должно**: пользователь вводит 11 цифр, первые 9 это номер, там через каждые три цифры должен ставится тире "-", потом еще две цифры должны быть через пробел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://dolbodub.blogspot.com/2013/03/edittext.html

Comment: @danilshik можете в качестве ответа указать конкретный пример?

Comment: а что не понятного? Я вроде вам источник скинул, вам необходимо только логику метода public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) реализовать и все